# Can't access a public S3 bucket from Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

I'm using Hadoop to process the Google Books ngrams, which are stored as Hadoop sequence files in Amazon S3.

Hadoop includes the capability to read from S3 (using the S3 bucket as a virtual "filesystem"), simply by specifying an s3:// or s3n:// protocol on the file name.

Unfortunately, it requires that you set your AWS access and secret keys. Since the bucket I'd like to read from is public, I don't have any keys to use. If I use my own keys, I can't read from the ngrams bucket (since it doesn't belong to my account).

How can I consume a file stored in a public S3 bucket from Hadoop, without re-hosting the file myself (which would get quite expensive, as there are a couple terabytes of data)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @AlexDean, I eventually gave up and wrote my own RecordReader that slurped in the file via HTTP. I never did get the default reader to work with S3.

Comment: Ah, shame, thanks for letting me know @levand. I've found that even S3DistCp has this limitation, which seems really dumb.

Answer (score -1):

If the data is public you will not need an AWS access or secret key because you will not use the `s3n://` variant. Instead you'll use the public URL variant, which will start with `http://*.s3.amazonaws.com/*`

If a public URL isn't available, you can try just passing in a blank string for each of the AWS access and secret keys and see what happens

Comment: Nope, unfortunately Hadoop can't mount its "filesystem" on the HTTP protocol like it can with S3.

Comment: I noticed that this page is linked at the bottom of Amazon's page for the NGrams dataset. It uses HIVE to work with that dataset. HIVE is just a framework that sits on top of Hadoop and it uses the same creds as hadoop would. http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5249664154115844

Comment: looks like this is indeed a limitation that hasn't been solved so far. Is there a JIRA ticket for it?

Comment: Facing the same problem here. Solved it by using jets3t directly, which is not nearly as elegant.